# How to upgrade to g++ 4.7 in SUSE linux

Tags: c++, linux, opensuse

I am new to linux.

I am trying to upgrade my g++ to version 4.7
If I type

```
g++ -v
```

it shows currently version

```
gcc version 4.1.2 20070115 (SUSE Linux)
```

I am trying to do the following

```
sudo zypper install gcc
```

Then I got:

```
Restoring system sources...
Parsing metadata for SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 10 SP4...
Parsing metadata for SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 10 SP4-20130716-134348...
Parsing RPM database...
skipping package 'gcc' (already installed)
Summary:
Nothing to do.
```

Please give me advise on what is the best way to do this.

Comment: Is this a company or university system you're on? Because if it's your own, I'm wondering why you're running a four year old distribution on there.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that your distro's repositories don't have the latest gcc version in them. So the best way is to download the gcc 4.7 source from http://gcc.gnu.org/ and compile from source.

EDIT: since your new to linux there is one thing that i just wanted to warn you about.
when you try to compile the source code don't compile it in the same directory instead create a directory called "build" or what ever inside the source code and then run compile from it like "$./../configure" and "$./../make" with what ever options you want from inside the build directory. this will save from a few headaches..

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to install gcc. Not update it

`zypper` tells you it is already installed. This is because the command you are running is the install command. You would need to use the `update` command.

example:

`zypper update gcc`

Now there is a good chance that the version currently installed is the highest available version, if this is the case then you would need to obtain the required version and compile from source as Abdullah's answer states.